# Editing xml on live in C#. Deleting nodes that contain specific value

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml document of type like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Recordset>
  <Table>Recordset</Table>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Fields>
        ...
        <Field>
          <Alias>StatusName</Alias>
          <Value>Scheduled</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field>
          <Alias>U_Revision</Alias>
          <Value>code00</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field>
          <Alias>U_Quantity</Alias>
          <Value>10.000000</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field>
          <Alias>U_ActualQty</Alias>
          <Value>0.000000</Value>
        </Field>
        ...
      </Fields>
    </Row>
    ...
    <Row>
      <Fields>
        ...
        <Field>
          <Alias>StatusName</Alias>
          <Value>Scheduled</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field>
          <Alias>U_Revision</Alias>
          <Value>code00</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field>
          <Alias>U_Quantity</Alias>
          <Value>150.000000</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field>
          <Alias>U_ActualQty</Alias>
          <Value>0.000000</Value>
        </Field>
        ...
      </Fields>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</Recordset>
```

I have different values in field with alias of StatusName. There are some Scheduled, notScheduled, Realeased, Finished etc values. What I would like to do is to delete each  node that contain  node with alias StatusName and value lets say Scheduled or Finished.

I was thinking to do this more or less in that way however I am doing something wrong. May anybody let me on right way ?

```
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
            XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Rows[@StatusName='Finished']");
            for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                nodes[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodes[i]);
            }
            var newXml = nodes.ToString();
```

I would like to delete the whole  node if contains  with alias StatusName and specific value lets say Finished.

I would expect the result in new string variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to work with DataTable with xml, I found it very easy. 
I used a DataTable to work with your nodes.
So, I took your xml file and wrote some code for you that might help you:

```
//READ THE XML FILE
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
//My path
xmlDoc.LoadXml(Properties.Resources.test);

//Read the xml file into a dataSet
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
XmlNodeReader xnr = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
ds.ReadXml(xnr);

//Your data will be store in the 4's dataTable of the dataSet ( the <field> )
for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[4].Rows.Count;i++)
{
    //Check the value as you wish
    //Here i want to suppress all the <Field> nodes with <Value> = "Scheduled"
    if ( ds.Tables[4].Rows[i]["Value"].ToString().Equals("Scheduled"))
    {
        //RemoteAt will remove all the node, so the node <Field> in your example data
        ds.Tables[4].Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        //If you want to only remove the node <Value>  (and not all the <Field> node ) just do ds.Tables[4].Rows["Value"]=null;
     }
}
//Write your new content in a new xml file

//As you wanted here you just read the new xml file created as a string
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
{
    ds.WriteXml(xmlTextWriter);
    xmlTextWriter.Flush();
    stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    //Here the result is in stringWriter,  and  there is 6 <Field> nodes, and not 8 like before the suppress
}

//If you want to create a new xml file with the new content just do 
ds.WriteXml(yourPathOfXmlFile);
//( like rewriting the previous xml file )
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It did not match my expected result  because I was expecting to delete the whole row, however thank to your code which inspired me, I have match my case. Thanks a lot ! Interesting topic those dataSets by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you are going to delete entire `<Row>` which matches your condition
i.e.,

```
<Row>
  <Fields>
    ...
    <Field>
      <Alias>StatusName</Alias>
      <Value>Finished</Value>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
</Row>
```

The required XPath:

```
//Row[Fields[Field[Alias[text()='StatusName'] and Value[text() = 'Finished']]]]
```

C#

```
string xPath = @"//Row[Fields[Field[Alias[text()='StatusName'] and Value[text() = 'Finished']]]]";
var nodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes(xPath);
for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    nodes[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodes[i]);
}
var newXml = xmlDocument.OuterXml;
```

Comment: You understood my expected result correctly. Thanks for anwer, I have done already the workaround as the Furtiro suggested me. This was much longer way however I did what I was expecting after changing some code. Anyway thank you for correcting my xPath. +